# Java-Spring-Hibernate: How can I save a filter and, afterward, how could I use it?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I receive a task for a project which uses Spring, Hibernate and Wicket.

In a particular HTML page I must have the possibility to create a filter(set the name of the filter and its parameters). I must create a list of filters in this way.
In the same time, I must have the possibility to edit and delete the filter, and of course, to use that filter.

Any ideas? How could I do this?

Comment: what filter? a javax.servlet.Filter, an application-specific filter or domain-specific filter.

Comment: application-specific filter
Based on this filter, I need to do a select in the database.

Answer (score 0):

if you're looking for a component to edit a list of items, then this might help: [Building a ListEditor form component](http://wicketinaction.com/2008/10/building-a-listeditor-form-component/)

you can use spring hibernate (or other ORM's) support to retrieve the data for your model without too much hassle.